# How do I put another "value" to look for into a.loc in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to look for info 'months_in_service" that could be 1, 2 or 3. Instead of put the code three times, what I can do instead?

```
axx = clean_df.loc[(clean_df['service_part_number'] == pn_list[3]) & (clean_df['months_in_service'] == 1), 'service_technician_comment']
```

Comment: `clean_df['months_in_service'].isin([1,2,3])`

Comment: Check out this post for more info: [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to give the [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.DataFrame.isin) method a shot.

```py
axx = clean_df.loc[(clean_df['service_part_number'] == pn_list[3]) & (clean_df['months_in_service'].isin([1,2,3])), 'service_technician_comment']
```

If you use the dictionary implementation of `isin`, you should be able to get the same results while placing whatever `equal` predicates you may have:

```py
axx = clean_df[clean_df.isin({"service_part_number": [pn_list[3]], "months_in_service", [1,2,3]})]["service_technician_comment"]
```

Just keep in mind, you cannot use `loc` when using `isin` like this, as it will raise: `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.isin([<list of items>])`

```
axx = clean_df.loc[(clean_df['service_part_number'] == pn_list[3]) & (clean_df['months_in_service'].isin([1, 2, 3]), 'service_technician_comment']
```